# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) using MAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I have a HTML form and I'm using PHP to send the results to an sql database on phpMyAdmin but after submitting I get "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" error.

This is all hosted locally using MAMP, root@localhost is the only user and I'm sure I've got the right password.

I've looked through similar questions, flushed privileges, created new users, tried logging on through the command line (to which I get the same error) but nothing seems to work.

Here's my code:

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "quotetool";

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO customerdetails (workstations, servers, firewalls, name, email, phone, support)
VALUES ('$workstations', '$servers', '$firewalls', '$name', '$email', '$phone', '$support')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
}
$conn->close();
```

and here is my user if this helps

[image]

[Screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuW3b.png)

Comment: You said $password ="root"; but if your database says its YES then why not change your variable to $password="YES";

Comment: This error comes when your username or password for connecting with database was wrong. I think your password root doesn't match.

Comment: Password form mamp is generally root by still try blank password.

Comment: @Tomm Just tried that, I get this: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Make sure that you have given **correct username and password**

Comment: Please check mysql server is start or not. When mysql server does not start then also we get same error. so please confirm mysql service is start or not.

Comment: Try this `$hostname = "127.0.0.1";` instead of this `$hostname = "localhost";`

Comment: @B.Desai I'm sure I have, and I've tried it with different users and passwords but still get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: *I've tried it with different users and passwords* but do you know you have given correct username password?

Comment: @RajendranNadar That gives me this: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @B.Desai Yes, whatever changes I make to users I match in PHP with the same results.

Comment: @Calle also make sure that you are changing and testing output of correct file. May be you are changing in other file and then test output

Comment: You are using MAC OS ?

Comment: Go to this file to check you credentials `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` just to make sure your values are correct. Somewhere near line no. 84

Comment: @RajendranNadar Yep, I have this: // MySQL port 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

Comment: Give a server restart. And try again with `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Abhijit No, Windows 8

Comment: @RajendranNadar Restarted the server but got the same result

Comment: can you login to the phpmyadmin from a web browser? If you are logged in logout and login again.

Comment: @RajendranNadar Logged out and back in but no change.

Comment: can you put the screenshot of the error in your question?

Comment: Hi,What is your php version to check php version.  Please go  to Preferences > PHP  and check php version.  What is your php version?

Comment: @Abhijit I'm using PHP 7.1.5

Comment: you able access to phpmyadmin? please share your error screen short

Comment: @Abhijit I can access phpmyadmin but I don't get an error there, only when I run PHP (I've updated my question with a screenshot of that error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code possibly it is because MySql expects Mamp to use port 3306.

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "quotetool";
$port = "8889";

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO customerdetails (workstations, servers, firewalls, name, email, phone, support)
VALUES ('$workstations', '$servers', '$firewalls', '$name', '$email', '$phone', '$support')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
}
$conn->close();
```

Correct syntax

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
```

If any issue let me know I will try fixing it.

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much. I actually changed $port = "3306"; to $port="8889" as this was the one sql was using but now it works great. Cheers!